# Widget not showing up in "search widgets" and im getting an error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, beta, widgetkit

I am using XCode 14 beta and for some reason, my widgets don't work in iOS 15, but only in 16. And Im also getting this error message:

```
SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show Widget 'com.click.distanceTester2.Lockscreen-Widgets' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x60000238c660 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to show Widget 'com.click.distanceTester2.Lockscreen-Widgets' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x60000238c660 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}., NSUnderlyingError=0x600002381680 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=5 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unexpected error type., NSUnderlyingError=0x60000238c660 {Error Domain=BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain Code=3 "XPC error received on message reply handler" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=OperationFailed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=XPC error received on message reply handler}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=InvalidResponse}}}
Domain: DTXMessage
Code: 1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-08-06 01:19:46 +0000";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 14.0 (21257.0.0.0.25) (Build 14A5229c)
Timestamp: 2022-08-05T18:19:46-07:00
```

Is anyone else having the same issue? Has anyone found any fixes? Thanks...

Comment: Have you figured this out by chance? I'm experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this is by getting the latest beta (as one option) or waiting for the Candidate release to come out. I fixed this issue by doing following, so ig just do that

Comment: I mean non-beta release, not CR

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).